# Weird profile picture URL with double query string

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, profile-picture

I just happened to notice that [this user's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/242620/random-oreilly) profile picture URL looks like this:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEJFV.gif?s=128&g=1?s=128&g=1
```

I don't know how that happened, but surely that's not intentional?

---

Ps. On the user's posts, the URL becomes:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEJFV.gif?s=128&g=1?s=32&g=1
```

Even this URL actually works, but it ends up loading the full 128 × 128 pixel image instead of the intended 32 × 32 pixel version.

Comment: Perhaps they copied a thumbnail from someone else?

Comment: Looks like a nice little hack to get a high res profile pic on you posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We were not stripping out pre-existing url parameters on the image url.

We are now.

With you in the next build (rev 2014.4.16.1551, meta rev 2014.4.16.2164).